# Import modules in Haskell

Tags: haskell

For a Haskell project I've just started, I have two files `Main.hs` and `Lib.hs`

However, I often find myself reaching for some modules that I've imported inside `Lib`  while working in `Main`.

Is there a way to automatically load in `Main.hs` all the modules already imported inside Lib?

**Lib.hs**

```
import System.Random
import Data.List 

{-
 Lib code here
-}
```

**Main.hs**

```
import Lib -- Importing should automatically imports System.Random and Data.List
main = undefined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modules can export other modules, including themselves (meaning they export all top level definitions instead of an explicit list of symbols you'd otherwise need to rely on).

```
module Lib ( module System.Random, module Data.List, module Lib) where
import System.Random
import Data.List 

{-
 Lib code here
-}
```

Comment: What I find quite nice is importing modules with a name and export this name, e.g. `module Lib (X) where` and `import System.Random as X`.